# OptaPlanner how to create your own .vrp

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to *OptaPlanner*. I would like to create my own *.vrp* file with my own data and import it in the *OptaPlanner*. To start I looked into the examples and duplicate one of these files and save it with another name.

I can view the content using notepad+ and I can edit these examples. I can save these files as *.vrp* in Notepad+ by just typing `file.vrp`.

This is probably not how I should do this since, if I import this file I only get an error.

How should I create a *.vrp* file and use the solver?

Answer (score 0):

OptaPlanner is a library for java programmers, the VRP example is just an example, which enterprises customize to their own needs. That being said, the `.vrp` format is defined by the VRP Web, see link in the docs section 3.